# What would be the natural way to draw someone who is pulling a wire or a rope from the ceiling?

Tags: inkscape, drawing

I'm having confusion on how to properly represent the motion of the human body. The action which I intend to draw is a man pulling a wire from the ceiling of a room. I attempted to look for sketches or examples of how this motion or figure would look like, but I don't know how would it look natural?.

My source of confusion is how would it look like if the cable is perpendicular to the ceiling as if the dummy is a piano mover or if the wire the dummy is pulling is makes an angle with the ceiling, will the motion look the same?.

Does it exist some reference or a stock of drawings displaying different poses and gestures of a person?.

I've found this sketch from below, which features a man pulling a rope but it comes from the sides not from the top, so I don't know how would it look like.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

How can this be drawn in Inkscape?. The wavy pattern, well there's a method to do it, but I don't know very well how to replicate the sketchy effect seen in the joints of the dummy.

Basically this question relates on how a dummy or a person would look like when it is pulling a wire from a top and how to draw this on Inkscape by following the pattern as seen in these dummies?.

Does it exist another stock or reference for different poses and gestures in a person?.

Comment: google: "electrician pulling wires from ceiling" or "lifting with pulley". Most artists also use a camera or mirror to help work out anatomy. Get a tripod and set the camera to timed delay and then take a picture of yourself.

Comment: https://www.human-anatomy-for-artist.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You live in a privileged era. You have references for everything, just search.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=poses&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images

And be more and more specific in your search:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pulling+a+rope&t=h_&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

The point fo your question is a specific camera angle, so you need to take a step further. Take those reference images and assign them to a 3D model.

You can use a 3D model and two free tools come to my mind.

Design doll https://terawell.net/terawell/?lang=en

And Daz 3D https://www.daz3d.com/home

The first one is really quick to set up the figure. On the second you have more realism but it takes more to set up the details, for example, the fingers. You can adapt some preset poses or make new ones.

Once the pose is prepared, you can change the camera angle (and the light) as you wish.

---

Be creative on your searches:

[Tarzan Rope](https://www.google.com/search?q=tarzan%20rope&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwiqjW9s_rAhXWW80KHX1BD1wQ_AUoAXoECDMQAw&biw=1475&bih=720)

[Worker pulling a rope](https://www.google.com/search?q=worker%20pulling%20a%20rope&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizrpHy9s_rAhVJAZ0JHc03BOEQ_AUoAXoECDMQAw&biw=1475&bih=720)

[Pulling a rope](https://www.google.com/search?q=pulling%20a%20rope&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiE25qO98_rAhXki60KHdDhDtcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pulling%20a%20rope&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQQzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHlC1KVjwK2C1LmgBcAB4AIABsgGIAbIBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=nGxSX4SdHeSXtgXQw7u4DQ&bih=720&biw=1475&client=firefox-b-d)

Comment: I think the main confusion was still left unattended, in other words, how to represent the motion of the person when he or she's pulling from the vertical or diagonal rope from a ceiling. In the sketches I could find it seems that the arms move back along the line of both shoulders. I did not make any mention about camera angle, but I intended that to be from the front as in the examples which I posted. The 3D model which you mentioned, how can I trace it in Inkscape?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend looking for examples on google.pictures. They are often "actors" posing and therefore a bit artificial. Why not get someone to actually pull on a rope hanging from the ceiling or a tree or... and take pictures of it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110940)